# Impresspages 4 Pagination Newslist

Tags: impresspages

I'm trying to create a blog on Impresspages 4 but on one side I would have a maximum of 10 entries.
Is there a way to pagination Newslist module?

Comment: Rzusto, why have you deleted the question about gmaps? I've prepared the answer :) and the question has gone :D

Comment: Mistake, sorry :) Already available :)

Answer (score 0):

This feature has not been implemented yet on existing Blog plugin.